# How to place every thing inside one game function to run the rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm finishing up my Rock, Paper, Scissor game and I need some guidance on how to execute all the functions I'd already created and store them into one main `game()` function. What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Play 5 rounds.
2. Keep track of their points.
3. Check who won the game.
4. Only run the user prompt once (not twice).

here is the full code: 
https://repl.it/@jl88s/rps

I have tried creating a `for loop` in order to track the number of rounds. Also, an `if statement` to check whether the `human` or `computer` has reached 5 points. One of the main problem for me is, having the prompt only executing once, but I'm not sure how to place the `humanPlay()` function inside the game function so it doesn't run twice.

```
function game() {
    for (let rounds = 1 ; rounds <= 5 ; rounds++) {
        let playerSelection = humanPlay();
        let computerSelection = computerPlay();

        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
        console.log(`Round ${rounds} [ Your score: ${playerScore} | Computer's score: ${computerScore} ]`);
    }

    if (playerScore === 5) {
        return "CONGRATULATIONS - YOU WON!";
    } else if (computerScore === 5) {
        return "THE COMPUTER HAS DEFEATED YOU! YOU LOSE!";
    } else {
        return "It's a draw!";
    }
}
```

I'm expecting for the `game()` function to `prompt` the user once and store the results of each round to the given winner, and having the game go up to the best of 5.

Comment: do you want the user to not be able to not have a choice after the first one or to not have the select one text oO ?

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt is executing twice because you call `humanPlay()` in `game()` and right after in `playRound()`, and then you do the `console.log()`.

Comment: So what is the solution for that?

Comment: remove : ` let playerSelection = humanPlay();
        let computerSelection = computerPlay();`

Comment: I think that you have to remove `let playerSelection = humanPlay();` and `let computerSelection = computerPlay();` from `game()` function.